# git – order commits introducing "TODO"s by date

Tags: git, git-log, todo

I want to find commits that <s>introduced</s> added a "TODO" or "FIXME" comment and order them by date.

I know that `git log -G'TODO|FIXME'` will show me commits that contain either comment and I could do something like

```
git log --format='%ci' -G'TODO|FIXME' | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

But this will not respect that it should only be commits *introducing* such comments.

Does anyone know how I can find only commits introducing such comments and order them by date? If the actual SHA-1 was included in that list, that would be even more awesome.

Comment: What do you mean by "introducing"? That these words have to be at the start of the commit message?

Comment: Sorry, no I meant that the commit *added* such a comment (opposed to a commit removing it or just changing a word in it)

Answer (score 5):

This should get you closer.  It isn't clear what you mean by "order them by date".  Personally I would probably ignore the actual dates and do reverse topo order.

Note - This will match commits that introduce or remove instances of the string.  If you only want commits that introduce you might need to script something.

`git log --format='%H' --reverse --date-order -G'TODO|FIXME'`

Answer (score 0):

not entirely what you want but will do a lot for you

```
git log -S TODO
```