# Git: speed up this command for searching Git blame for todos

Tags: linux, git

I'm using this command:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD -- . | grep -E '\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|css|scss|html)$' | xargs -n1 git blame -c -e | sed -E 's/^.+\.com>\s+//' | LC_ALL=C grep -F 'todo: ' | sort
```

This gets all the todos in my codebase, sorted by date. This is mostly from [Use git to list TODOs in code sorted by date introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871473/use-git-to-list-todos-in-code-sorted-by-date-introduced), I'm not very good with the command line.

However, the `grep 'todo: '` part takes a long time. It takes 1min for ~400 files, without any particularly large files. Is it possible to speed this up somehow?

**Edit:** I realized it's the `git blame` that's slow, not `grep`, so I did a search before running `git blame`:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD -- . | grep -E '\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|css|scss|html)$' | LC_ALL=C xargs grep -F -l 'todo: ' | xargs -n1 git blame -c -e | sed -E 's/^.+\\.com>\\s+//' | LC_ALL=C grep -F 'todo: ' | sort
```

Now it's 6s.

Comment: You can do better for instance  just `git grep -il todo: \*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css,scss,html}` to generate the list.

Comment: How many files do you have todos in? I guess you could use `git grep --name-only` either as the first step, or as a filtering step between list of files and blame. If only some files have todos, it will save you running costly blame on all the rest of files.

Comment: @jthill that looks useful! It works when I run it directly in the terminal, but when I use it as a Yarn script, I get `usage: git blame [<options>] [<rev-opts>] [<rev>] [--] <file>`. Any ideas why `git grep` produces the error but not `git ls-tree`?

Comment: @Frax About 30 files have todos. `git grep -il todo: \*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,css,scss,html}` is really fast already

Comment: I don't know Yarn, it could be it doesn't do brace expansion so the blame gets no file args?